# detect multiple patterns in one string - python-regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, spyder

I edited the below regex, as per the answer I received on this question.

My string has a mix of year and month terms.
I need to detect both with regex.

```
String1 = " I have total exp of 10-11 years. This includes 15yearsin SAS and 5 
years in python. I also have 8 months of exp in R programming."

import re
pat= re.compile(r'\d{1,3}(?:\W+\d{1,3})?\W+(?:plus\s*)?(?:year|month|Year|Month)s?\b', re.X)
experience = re.findall(pat,String1 )    
print(experience)
['10-11 years', '5 years', '8 months']
```

But I also want the terms without space i.e. 15years ( as I am reading from free flowing text).

Can anybody please help to achieve the right regex?

Comment: So, `['10-11 years', '5 years in SAS and 5 years', '8 month']` is the expected output?

Comment: Are you sure you do not need `['10-11 years', '5 years', '5 years', '8 month']` in fact?

Comment: yes @WiktorStribiżew ['10-11 years', '5 years', '5 years', '8 month']  is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
r'\b\d{1,2}(?:\D+\d{1,2})?\D+(?:year|month)s?\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rpWBkA/1) that outputs `['10-11 years', '15 years in SAS and 5 years', '8 months']`.

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `(?:\D+\d{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\D+` - 1+ chars other than a digit
  - `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `\D+` -  one or more non-digit chars
- `(?:year|month)` - a `year` or `month`
- `s?` - an optional `s`
- `\b` - word boundary.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/VX9Zj3):

```
import re
String1 = " I have total exp of 10-11 years. This includes 15 years in SAS and 5 years in python. I also have 8 months of exp in R programming."
reg = r'\b\d{1,2}(?:\D+\d{1,2})?\D+(?:year|month)s?\b'
print(re.findall(reg, String1))
# => ['10-11 years', '15 years in SAS and 5 years', '8 months']
```

**NOTE**: If you plan to get `['10-11 years', '15 years', '5 years', '8 months']` replace `\D+` with `\W+` (*one or more chars other than letters, digit, underscore*) and use

```
r'\b\d{1,2}(?:\W+\d{1,2})?\W+(?:year|month)s?\b'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rpWBkA/2).

Comment: @Riya Please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: It did not work for patterns like .. '3 plus years' as the regex is selecting W+. Example: Exp in skill1 is 3+ years and exp in skill2 is 6 plus years. Both **3+ years** and **6 plus years** must get detected by the regex. Any way to do this?

Comment: @Riya Add an optional group, see `r'\b\d{1,2}(?:\W+\d{1,2})?\W+(?:plus\s*)?(?:year|month)s?\b'` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rpWBkA/3).

Comment: I accepted the answer. Also modifying my question a little to include a new feature.

Comment: okay...my apologies...done that now...can you please help me with this new addition? The regex is not detecting terms like 5years as there is no space in the middle. Even if it is 5yearsand..it should get 5years as it ends with 'years'.

Comment: @Riya Replace `\D+` with `\D*` before `year` matching pattern, `\b\d{1,2}(?:\D+\d{1,2})?\D*(?:year|month)s?\b`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rpWBkA/4).

Comment: I am using the expressions as mentioned in the question- \d{1,3}(?:\W+\d{1,3})?\W+(?:plus\s*)?(?:year|month|Year|Month)s?\b. Replacing + with *  worked on 4years but not on 4yearsand. I need to mention that the phrase ends with years. Where to put the $ sign?

Comment: @Riya Same stuff. Make `\W` match 0 or more chars with `*`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rpWBkA/6). You do not need `$` unless you want to find something at the end of the string.

Comment: in the demo--  instead of '8 months of', if I write '8monthsof', it fails to detect 8months. This is the problem I am facing.

Comment: @Riya Ok, then remove the `\b` word boundary from the end. If you do not want to ensure whole word match why use the limiting pattern? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rpWBkA/7).